# RecyclerView and scrolling indicators

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Im using `RecyclerView` and I wanna use scroll indicators (showing that you scrolled to the start/end of `RecyclerView`) instead of scrollbars. My `RecyclerView` is horizontal.

Is there any way how to enable this like in `ScrollView`?

Comment: did you  check that https://guides.codepath.com/android/endless-scrolling-with-adapterviews-and-recyclerview

Comment: I dont need endless scrolling. My Recyclerview is not endless. I just want to show that user has reached end of RecyclerView without showing him horizontal scrollbar below (which is not pretty from UI PoV)